# setNextMediaPlayer throws Next player can't be self

Tags: android

When I try to `setNextMediaPlayer` it throws Next player can't be self, I don't understand what it is. Thanks in advance.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private void createNextMediaPlayer(int resource) {

        Uri url = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + mService.getPackageName() + "/" + resource);
        mNextPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mNextPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mNextPlayer.setDataSource(mService, url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mNextPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mNextPlayer.setWakeMode(mService.getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        mNextPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if (mCurrentPlayer != null)
                    mCurrentPlayer.setNextMediaPlayer(mp); //ERROR
            }
        });
        if (mCurrentPlayer != null)
            mCurrentPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletionListener);
        mOnCompleteResId = resource;
    }
```

> 07-29 20:35:46.543 14771-14771/com.supermedaiplayer E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 Process: com.supermedaiplayer, PID: 14771
>                                                                                 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Next player can't be self
>                                                                                     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setNextMediaPlayer(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at god.mediaplayers.LocalPlayer$2.onPrepared(LocalPlayer.java:410)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:2871)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, all I found the bug myself hope my answer might some one.

I was passing `mp` obtained from `onPrepare(Mediaplayer mp)` to `mCurrentPlayer.setNextMediaPlayer(mp);` which some how happened to be same as `mCurrentPlayer` which was causing problem.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setNextMediaPlayer(android.media.MediaPlayer)) "The next MediaPlayer must be different from 'this'. An exception will be thrown if next == this." so I passed `mNextPlayer` to `mCurrentPlayer.setNextMediaPlayer(mNextPlayer);` which did the trick.

I updated the code with a fix:

```
private void createNextMediaPlayer(int resource) {

        Uri url = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + mService.getPackageName() + "/" + resource);
        mNextPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mNextPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mNextPlayer.setDataSource(mService, url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mNextPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mNextPlayer.setWakeMode(mService.getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        mNextPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if (mCurrentPlayer != null) {
                    LogHelper.d(TAG, "Checking reference for mp", mCurrentPlayer, " ", mp);
                    LogHelper.d(TAG, "Checking reference for mNextPlayer ", mCurrentPlayer, " ", mNextPlayer);
                    mCurrentPlayer.setNextMediaPlayer(mNextPlayer);
                }
            }
        });
        if (mCurrentPlayer != null)
            mCurrentPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletionListener);
        mOnCompleteResId = resource;
    }
```

UPDATE:

In my case, it happened onPrepared was being called multiple times. At some point, the `mNextPlayer` was not prepared so it was crashing again with a message mNextPlayer was not prepared so I tweaked the code to match my requirements.

Code:

```
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if (mCurrentPlayer != null && mp != mCurrentPlayer) {
                    mCurrentPlayer.setNextMediaPlayer(mp);
                }
            }
```